# ASP.NET MVC Web API Attribute Routing With overloads

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have two methods for getting a list of projects, or an individual project. However, when I try to implement attribute routing I get a '405 Method Not Allowed' error. One method takes a string (returning a list of projects), the other an integer (returning a single project), how can I get the routing to work?

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/projects/{search}")]
public List<JsonProject> Get(string search = null)
{
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("api/projects/{id:int}")]
public JsonProject Get(int id)
{
}
```

The 'search' parameter is optional (by default it returns all records) and I may want to add 'sort' as well (also optional). If I take `Route` out I can get the list of projects, but not the individual project

global.asax has

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

and the routing

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;

        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);

    }
}
```

Comment: Check the `Allow` header in your `405 Method Not Allowed` response and let us know what it tells

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add another route for the search parameter. It's for when the search is null, it will work.See below:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/projects/")]
[Route("api/projects/{search}")]
public List<JsonProject> Get(string search = null){ }
```

Also, try to remove the WebDav handler and WebDav module from web.config and change the ExtensionlessUrl handler verb attribute.

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>

  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: That would maybe mean I need to `if else` in the same action method to call different methods e.g. from a service? Isn't there something like an overloading so I don't need to use conditions?